# How can I test different endpoints of an API in Mocha when endpoint depend on each other

Tags: mocha.js

Using Mocha to test a Rest-API. Every endpoint gets its own Mocha test.
The Mocha-BeforeAll empties the database and tests fill up their own test data.

In a certain endpoint data is added to the database and another one then retrieves it back.

```
    describe('Testing endpoint /users/add', function () {
        it ('should successfully add data', function(done) {
            /// Call API endpoint with supertest to add some data
            .end(function (err, res) {
                res.status.should.be(200);
                done();
            })
        })
    });

    describe('Testing endpoint /users to get the data', function () {
        it ('should successfully retrieve the data', function (done) {
            /// Call API endpoint with supertest to retrieve data
            .end(function (err, res) {
                res.status.should.be.eql(200);
                res.body.should.have.property('users').with.lengthOf(1);
                done();
            })
        })
    });
```

However, what happens is that the second describe returns an empty array. The 'add' endpoint is just slower than 'retrieve'.

Also tried to put both 'it' statements in one 'describe', but same result: Empty array from the retrieve.

Question is: How to make the async tests run sychronously

General question is: How to test different endpoints of an API in Mocha when endpoint depend on each other

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it myself. 
Although the code-example seems to show only one supertest call per 'it' section, in reality I had more than one supertest call in an 'it' section with only one done() at the end. Those server-calls fired off and the done() was executed (not waiting on the individual server calls)

If you use the done-callback, then Mocha waits.